# Botão que adicione componentes no template do vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Oi,

Existe alguma lógica para adicionar vários componentes dentro do template do Vue de acordo com o número de vezes que eu clique no botão?

Por exemplo, no código tenho botão e vários componentes, mas gostaria que esses componentes só aparecessem de acordo com o número de cliques do botão

```
    <template>
        <div class="col-1 p-1 px-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary w-100">-</button>
        </div>
        <AddressField />
        <AddressField />
        <AddressField />
        <AddressField />
        <AddressField />
        <AddressField />
        <AddressField />
        <AddressField />
        <AddressField />
    <template>

    <script>
        import AddressField from './AddressField.vue';
        export default {
        name: 'InputAddress',
        components: {
            AddressField,
        },
    }
</script>
```

Portanto, meu objetivo é não ter vários componentes, mas sim um botão ao usuário para ele criar quantos componentes ele deseja ver na sua tela.

Muito obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você terá que utilizar o `v-for` do vue para isso. De uma olhada [aqui](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#v-for)

Segue abaixo um exemplo.

```js
 new Vue({
    el: '#app', //Tells Vue to render in HTML element with id "app",
    data() {
      return {
        count: 0
      }
    }
  });
  
 Vue.component("addr",{
  name:"address",
  props:{
    index: Number
  },
  template: `
    <div>
    Endereço {{index}}
    </div>
  `
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="count++">Novo endereço</button>
  <div v-for="index in count" >
    <addr :index="index" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oi, Guto! Muito obrigado pela resposta ;)

Eu usei a lógica do v-for, mas usei como base o link da documentação que você deixou para mim

Valeu ;) 

A resposta eu deixei abaixo

Answer (score -2):

Lógica usada:

```
    <ul class="p-0">
                <address-field
                    v-for="(addressfield) in AddressFieldObject"
                    :key="addressfield.id"
                    :title="addressfield.title"
                ></address-field>
    </ul>

No script:
    <script>
        import AddressField from './AddressField.vue';
        export default {
        name: 'InputAddress',
        components: { AddressField },
        data() {
            return {
                newAddressField: '', 
                AddressFieldObject: [

            ],
            nextAddressFieldID: 1
            }
        },   
        methods: {
            addAddressField() {
                this.AddressFieldObject.push({
                    id: this.nextAddressFieldID++,
                })
                this.newAddressField = ''
            }
    }
</script>
```